# CASE query answer data type changes depending on the data type of the unused statement

Tags: mysql, sql, case

I have a simple CASE query, however I noticed something I find surprising - the type of data that the query returns changes depending on what data type is in the unused (not chosen) branch.

Let's consider two case queries:

A1:

```
SELECT
CASE 1 
WHEN 3 THEN '7'
ELSE 'text answer' END
FROM SomeDatabase
```

B1:

```
SELECT
CASE 1
WHEN 3 THEN '7'
ELSE float_attribute END
FROM SomeDatabase
```

The A1 query will return 'the same'
The B1 query will return the value of float_attribute (which is of the float type - important!)
So far so good...

The issue I have is if we change these queries so that the condition is fullfilled

A2:

```
SELECT
CASE 1 
WHEN 1 THEN '7'
ELSE 'the same' END
FROM SomeDatabase
```

B2:

```
SELECT
CASE 1
WHEN 1 THEN '7'
ELSE float_attribute END
FROM SomeDatabase
```

Now here is where my confusion starts:

Query A2 returns 7

Query B2 returns 7.000000

Despite both queries containing the same chosen branch **WHEN 1 THEN '7'**
the queries return a value of a different type.

Clearly, the type depends on the type of the value/attribute that's in the second branch, even when it isn't chosen.

WHY IS THAT?? Is that normal SQL behaviour?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not surprising at all.  A `CASE` expressions returns a *single* value.  That value has a specified type.

The rules for determining the type of the return value have a preference for numbers and dates over strings.  So if *any* of the return values is a number, then the overall value is a number.  This is an easy way to get conversion errors, in some databases.

This is standard behavior.  I'm pretty sure every data documents this as part of the explanation of the `CASE` expression.

Comment: Thanks, didn't know that and couldn't find any information on that regarding the CASE expression. Once the 15 minutes pass since posting this question I will mark it as solved

Comment: @Niteraleph . . . If you tag your question with the database, I can point to the documentation there.

Answer (score 1):

The `CASE` statement *Returns the highest precedence type from the set of types in result_expressions and the optional else_result_expression. For more information, see [Data Type Precedence (Transact-SQL)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/data-types/data-type-precedence-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15).* [Reference](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/language-elements/case-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15)

In your case, string is lower than float.